# Rails formal argument cannot be an instance variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails error and I don't know where to look to solve it. On a "products#show" I get this

```
SyntaxError at /products/63  formal argument cannot be an instance variable
```

I commented everything out of the controller and the view

```
def show
  # @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end
```

My error gem points me to activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb

```
  newly_defined_paths = new_constants_in(*parent_paths) do
    result = Kernel.load path     #this is the line with the error
  end
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, From which line in the code it is coming from, can you add views also.

Comment: the view is blank i removed it and the error still occurs

Comment: Which version of ruby you are using, is it coming after ruby-1.9.1, and was working fine earlier, detailed error logs will surely help to debug.

Comment: it was working fine earlier i am using ruby 2.1.0. and I got it the log pointed to a method i commented out the method and it works fine. Thanks !!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error usually comes up when you have an invalid block parameter name.

For example `@products.each do |@product| ...` or `@products.each do |Product|...` should both 
be `@products.each do |product|`.

Check your `products/show` view file and make sure your block parameters are all lower case words without the `@` symbol.

It's also possible this is in a method definition somewhere (`def my_method(@var)...`)

Comment: Can you post more of the stack trace? Do any of the lines point to any files in your project?

Comment: I dont know how to make a stack trace and my debugger points to libraries nothing in my app really