# Ruby - "formal argument cannot be a class variable"

Tags: ruby

I've never used Ruby before, and am attempting to run a program written way back in 2006. I've installed Ruby and the gem package OK, but when I try to run it, I get an error:

```
xmltv2html.rb:231: formal argument cannot be a class variable

xmltv2html.rb:231: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting '|'
```

The area giving me trouble in particular is

```
     def parse_command_line_options
     ARGV.options do
        |opts|
        opts.banner = "Usage: #{File.basename($0)} < xmltv.xml > tv.html\n"


        # separater
        opts.on_tail
        opts.on_tail("common options:")

        opts.on("--configfile=FILE", String, "config file to use") {
           |@@options[:config_file]|}

        #more code after
```

The project I'm trying to use is 'xmltv2html'.

Is there something in particular I'm doing wrong? I've tried changing the '|@@options' to '|@options' and '|$options' but that just changes the error message to reflect the relevant scope.

Is it just a case of using a project that is too old?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails formal argument cannot be an instance variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092993/rails-formal-argument-cannot-be-an-instance-variable)

Comment: Check your code at `|@@options[:config_file]|` - this is an invalid parameter for a block

Comment: @Slava.K any suggestions for a newbie? Remembering this is not my code and I've never used Ruby, I'm trying to get my head around it all!

Comment: You may try to find and install ruby version that was used back in 2006. The oldest available in rbenv is 1.8.6-p383 - it was released in 2007. However I believe internet remembers everything, and, probably, other old ruby versions exist somewhere

Comment: I'm voting to leave this one open.  I've voted to close the [nominated examplar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092993/rails-formal-argument-cannot-be-an-instance-variable) instead.  Although that question's title is similar to what's being asked here, the question itself doesn't show any code that would cause that error; this question does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assignment semantics for block parameters were removed in Ruby 1.9.0 (released in 2007). You will have to restructure the code to perform the assignment yourself, something like this:

```
opts.on("--configfile=FILE", String, "config file to use") do |config_file| 
  @@options[:config_file] = config_file
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. Your recommendations worked well in resolving the error and in furthering my knowledge.